# typescript : async function as argument of another function is executed instead of pending

Tags: arrays, typescript, parallel-processing, promise

I'm trying to create generic functions that level off the number of promises running in parallel. the main topic is to control the google API calls to avoid reaching some quotas defined by google.

I'm creating an array of value.
Then I'm looping through this array, and creating an array of Promises. Each promises is calling a function with the value as argument.
Finally, I'm running a promise.all for each chunk of X pending promises

Unfortunatly, when creating the array of "pending" promises, the function passed as argument is executed. As a result, controling the concurrent execution via Promise.all is useless.

Below is the code.
Rgds

**function that creates the array of promises with the function as argument**

```
 const createArrayOfFunctionPromise = <T>(
  arrayVal: T[],
  functionToExecute: (...args: any[]) => any
): Array<Promise<T[]>> => {
  const resu: Array<Promise<T[]>> = [];
  arrayVal.forEach((val: T, index: number) => {
    resu.push(functionToExecute(val, index));
  });
  return resu;
};
```

**Function that executes the array of promises by chunk**

```
const executeArrayOfFunctionPromiseByChunk = async <T>(
  arrValue: T[],
  functionToExecute: (...args: any[]) => any,
  chunk?: number
): Promise<T[]> => {
  const arrP: Array<Promise<T[]>> = createArrayOfFunctionPromise<T>(
    arrValue,
    functionToExecute
  );
  let data: T[][] = [];
  if (chunk) {
    if (chunk > 0) {
      let tmpArr: Array<Promise<T[]>> = [];
      for (let i: number = 0; i < arrP.length; i += 1) {
        tmpArr.push(arrP[i]);
        if (i % chunk === 0 || i === arrP.length - 1) {
          const d = await Promise.all(tmpArr);
          data.push(d.flat(1));
          tmpArr = [];
        }
      }
    } else {
      return [];
    }
  } else {
    data = await Promise.all(arrP);
  }
  // console.log(data);
  return data.flat(1);
};
```

**example of function to execute**

```
const dummyFunction = async (val: string, index: number): Promise<string[]> => {
  let resu: string[] = [];

  resu = [...resu, await dummyPromise<string>(`${val} appel 1`, index)];
  resu = [...resu, await dummyPromise<string>(`${val} appel 2`, index + 0.5)];
  resu = [...resu, await dummyPromise<string>(`${val} appel 3`, index + 1.2)];
  resu = [...resu, await dummyPromise<string>(`${val} appel 4`, index + 1.7)];
  resu = [...resu, await dummyPromise<string>(`${val} appel 5`, index + 0.7)];
  return resu;
};

const dummyPromise = async <T>(param: T, index: number): Promise<T> => {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve(param), 3 * index * 1000);
    console.log("dans dummypro", 3 * index * 1000);
  });
};
```

***test program to run - should execute the function dummyFunction 2 by 2 (chunk=2) while looping the array of 3 elements***

```
const test = async (array: string[]): Promise<string[]> => {
  const result: string[] = await executeArrayOfFunctionPromiseByChunk<string>(
    array,
    dummyFunction,
    2
  );
  return result;
};

test(["a", "b", "c"]).then((result: string[]) => {
  console.log(result.flat(1));
  });
```

Comment: that's because you're executing it here : `resu.push(functionToExecute(val, index))`. If instead, you pushed a function that calls your function : `()=>resu.push(functionToExecute(val, index))`, you can then control when the function is called at the business end.

Comment: uhm not sure to understand. If I add this piece of code, the arrayofPromises is empty... `const createArrayOfFunctionPromise =  <T>(
  arrayVal: T[],
  func: (...args: any[]) => any
): Array<Promise<T[]>> => {
  const resu: Array<Promise<T[]>> = [];
  arrayVal.forEach((val: T, index: number) => {
    return ()=>resu.push(func(val, index))
  });
  console.log(resu);
  return resu;
};`